# Android Thread with Methods

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I have this sittuation:

3 public methods, 2 are commands and 1 check inputs and will start command1 or command2 in thread. My question is how i can do that?

```
public void blablabla() {
    input = get_user_input;

    if(input == 1) {
        start thread with command1
    } else {
        start thread with command2
    }
}

public void command1() {
    // do action
}

public void command2() {
    // do action2
}
```

I think its impossible start a thread with method directly but using Runnable i can do that. I was thinking if its good choice and great idea for performance declare command1 and command2 are static runnable on class and use this runnables to start thread. Doing this as static runnable it will spend more memory than a method ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Asyn thread. try this below example

```
private class GetExampleDetails extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(ExpensesListView.this);
    String strMsg = null;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Loading.....");
        this.dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
        this.dialog.show();

    }

    // automatically done on worker thread (separate from UI thread)
    protected Void doInBackground(final String... a) {

        try
        {

            //Write your code. which one do backround
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    // can use UI thread here
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void unused) {


        if (this.dialog.isShowing()) {
            this.dialog.dismiss();
            this.dialog = null;
        }


    }

}//Endtask
```

check this one. i think this help you